# NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS setting for decimal

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have one db setup in a test machine and second in production machine. When I run:

```
select to_number('100,12') from dual
```

Then it gives error in test machine. However, this statement works quite fine in production machine.

Now, when I check for NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS then I see ',' (comma) in both machine. Is there anywhere else I should be looking for the decimal setting?

Cheers!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can see your current session settings by querying `nls_session_parameters`:

```
select value
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';

VALUE                                  
----------------------------------------
.,
```

That may differ from the database defaults, which you can see in `nls_database_parameters`.

In this session your query errors:

```
select to_number('100,12') from dual;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
```

I could alter my session, either directly with `alter session` or by ensuring my client is configured in a way that leads to the setting the string needs (it may be inherited from a operating system or Java locale, for example):

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
select to_number('100,12') from dual;

TO_NUMBER('100,12')
-------------------
             100,12
```

In SQL Developer you can set your preferred value in Tool->Preferences->Database->NLS.

But I can also override that session setting as part of the query, with the optional third *nlsparam* parameter to [`to_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions211.htm); though that makes the optional second *fmt* parameter necessary as well, so you'd need to be able pick a suitable format:

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';
select to_number('100,12', '99999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')
from dual;

TO_NUMBER('100,12','99999D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')
--------------------------------------------------------------
                                                        100.12
```

By default the result is still displayed with my session settings, so the decimal separator is still a period.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the problem was with client software. I was using oracle developer in one machine while PL/SQL developer in another.

Comment: Is it possible to add "DEFAULT -1 ON CONVERSION ERROR" into your very last select query when using to_number? It causes an Oracle error ORA-43918 in my case.

Comment: @gouessej - it wasn't when I wrote this answer *8-) But [yes, it is](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91283443f9c364d61d0563e8ece43690). Maybe you're seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037721/266304)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your example works when the first parameter is a literal but not when it's a column name. I've just tried with Oracle 19. The hint doesn't help.

Comment: [It does work with a column](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=826c0ede0b6cb3796095184369452fe3) - so not sure what's different for you. (That hint might only apply for 12c; but then it should work without it in later versions). It might be worth asking a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: Ok I found the problem. It works as expected in a simple example but when I add this part into a more complicated select query, it fails, Oracle seems to lose the information of a parameter type. I wrote a reproducer yesterday, I'll post it somewhere Monday. I simplified the query a lot, it allowed me to work around the problem but I still think that the original query should have worked as is. By the way, the reproducer is self-contained and the pseudo-table contains only one line.

Comment: @AlexPoole Maybe you'd like to give it a look: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af484b133e845837c2d550bfcf6bdd2c I get an error "ORA-43918: This argument must be a literal" :s

Comment: It's interesting, and you could ask a new question about it; but it looks like a bug so you'd probably be better off raising an SR with Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

*Jaanna*, the **session** parameters in *Oracle SQL Developer* are dependent on your client computer, while the **NLS** parameters on *PL/SQL* is from server.

For example the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` on client computer can be '*,.*' while it's '*.,*' on server.

So when you run script from *PL/SQL* and *Oracle SQL Developer* the decimal separator can be completely different for the same script, unless you alter session with your expected `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` in the script.

One way to easily test your session parameter is to do:

```
select to_number(5/2) from dual;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your example ! Why 5/2 and not 5,2 ? If your code is correct, I missunderstand something :-)

Comment: No mention of PL/SQL in the OP question

Comment: @schlebe So you can check if the decimal separator (dot or comma) is ok in the output of the select statement

Answer (score 0):

To know SESSION decimal separator, you can use following SQL command:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ', ';

select SUBSTR(value,1,1) as "SEPARATOR"
      ,'using NLS-PARAMETER' as "Explanation"
  from nls_session_parameters
  where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'

UNION ALL

select SUBSTR(0.5,1,1) as "SEPARATOR" 
      ,'using NUMBER IMPLICIT CASTING' as "Explanation"
  from DUAL;
```

The first SELECT command find NLS Parameter defined in `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` table. The decimal separator is the first character of the returned value.

The second SELECT command convert IMPLICITELY the `0.5` rational number into a String using (by default) NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS defined at session level.

The both command return same value.

I have already tested the same SQL command in PL/SQL script and this is always the same value COMMA or POINT that is displayed. Decimal Separator displayed in PL/SQL script is equal to what is displayed in SQL.

To test what I say, I have used following SQL commands:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ', ';

select 'DECIMAL-SEPARATOR on CLIENT: (' || TO_CHAR(.5,) || ')' from dual;

DECLARE
    S VARCHAR2(10) := '?';
BEGIN

    select .5 INTO S from dual;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DECIMAL-SEPARATOR in PL/SQL: (' || S || ')');
END;
/
```

The shorter command to know decimal separator is:

```
SELECT .5 FROM DUAL;
```

That return `0,5` if decimal separator is a COMMA and `0.5` if decimal separator is a POINT.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is,

```
SELECT to_number(replace(:Str,',','')/100) --into num2 
FROM dual;
```

Comment: When using code in a question, please put all code into code blocks: usually, indent all code lines by 4 spaces, or surround the code block with 3 backticks (`\`\`\``). For inline code on the same line as non-code, surround the code with a single backtick on each side (`\``).