# decimal separator oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal

I need to replace comma with point and then i need my value to be a number. 
So i wrote this:

```
select replace('12345,6789', ',' , '.') from dual --it works fine
```

but then I want to convert `to_number` that value and I get the error:

> `"invalid number"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NLS\_NUMERIC\_CHARACTERS setting for decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571355/nls-numeric-characters-setting-for-decimal)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`to_number()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions211.htm#SQLRF06140) uses the session's [NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams154.htm#REFRN10126) setting to decide how to interpret commas and periods. If you know your string will always have a comma as decimal separator you can override that as part of the call, using the optional third argument; although that does mean you have to specify the format model:

```
select to_number('12345,6789', '9999999999D9999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')
from dual;

TO_NUMBER('12345,6789','9999999999D9999
---------------------------------------
                             12345.6789
```

You don't need a separate `replace()` step.

You can also change the session's setting with [`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=',.';`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2013.htm#SQLRF00901), but you may not be able to control the setting in every client that has to run your code.

Comment: I have run into some problems with this solution. I checked the parameter NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS. It's set correctly with values `',.'`. But when I try to convert string to number the decimal delimiter disappears. See: https://gist.github.com/kovalensue/52383a9d138ea39584ff854b58c6dc4e

Comment: @kovalensue - this question is more than four years old, so you should ask a new question if you have a follow-on issue. But the v$paramater value is `.,` not `,.`; but in any case its your session value that matters, so check what is shown in the `nls_session_parameters` view. If you do `alter session` as shown in the answer then your query gets `213174,11`. Or include the third argument, as shown.

Answer (score 2):

The decimal separator is defined in your locale. Here it looks like it is `,`. So you need not to do the replacement before converting your string:

```
select to_number('12345.6789') from dual --should work already
```

Or change your locale:

```
alter session  set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= '.,';
select to_number('123'||'.'||'456') from dual;
select to_number(replace('12345,6789', ',' , '.')) from dual
```