# Why does this query in SQL Developer cause this error?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Why do I get the error shown when I try to run this query in SQL Developer:

```
DECLARE
    p_latitude number;
BEGIN
    p_latitude:=TO_NUMBER(LTRIM(RTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('BT1 1AA|54.60240|-5.92214|875082434', '[^|]+', 1, 2),'"'),'"'));
END;
```

Error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
>   ORA-06512: at line 4

Can anyone help me solve this error?

Expected output:

54.60240

Comment: Possible duplicate of [decimal separator oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739525/decimal-separator-oracle)

Comment: Can you post the output of `select value
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';`?

Comment: The output is ,.

Comment: Since you are expected to read decimals separated by `"." `  , there's no reason why it is set to  `,.` , quite possibly by a mistake ?  read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38739718/7998591) answer to know the details of the error and  how to modify it

Answer (score 1):

I think you can manage it by such a conversion :

```
DECLARE
 p_latitude number;
BEGIN
 with t(nr) as
 (
  select LTRIM(RTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('BT1 1AA|54.60240|-5.92214|875082434', '[^|]+', 1, 2),'"'),'"') 
     from dual
 )
 select to_number(replace(nr,'.',','),'fm99G990D00000','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')
   into p_latitude
   from t;
END;
```

Comment: Hi Barbaros, I want the output to be 54.60240

Comment: @SindhuChoudary you already have the dotted format, without `to_number` conversion. I mean formatting is not important for a numeric variable provided the decimal part is determined.