# Error, invalid number Jasperstudio and Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, jaspersoft-studio, ora-01722

In the following SQL:

```
select cast(parvalor as float) valor from parametros where parid = 26
```

I want to get the data in decimal, use TO_NUMBER and CAST (XX AS FLOAT) but it does not work.

This query runs in ORACLE 12c and works normal, but when I execute it in JasperStudio 6.3, I get

error ORA-01722: invalid number.

I really have no idea where the error is, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, changing data decimal "," to ".", jasper recognized query, but in oracle no is functional, what is the problem?

Comment: Solve the problem with here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571355/nls-numeric-characters-setting-for-decimal)