# Convert string to decimal Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I intended convert data type string to decimal  in Oracle data base and i get this error:

> ORA-01722: número no válido 01722. 00000 - "invalid number" *Cause:
>   The specified number was invalid. *Action: Specify a valid number

Code:

```
TO_NUMBER('5.0') AS numero

CAST('5.0' AS NUMBER) AS numero
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NLS\_NUMERIC\_CHARACTERS setting for decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571355/nls-numeric-characters-setting-for-decimal)

Answer (score 1):

```
select TO_NUMBER('5.0') from dual;

select NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS
 from v$nls_parameters;

 --There must be '.' in value filed to run above query
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted works fine for me.

However, check you NLS/locale settings. If I change mine to use something other that '.' as the decimal separator then I get the same error.

So it would appear that it may be down to your locale settings. You can check with `select * from v$nls_parameters` to see what the `nls_numeric_characters` is set to.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answeres, it served as a guide to find the root of the problem. verifying the local configuration of nls_numeric_characters encontre ',.'
Apparently the server configuration is different and therefore caused the error in the Query.

To give solution, replace '.' by ',' I assumed the configuration of nls_numeric_characters on the server is with ','.

```
select TO_NUMBER(REPLACE('5.0','.',',')) from dual;
```

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571355/nls-numeric-characters-setting-for-decimal contains more information related to my solution