# convert text/string to number/int for python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

may I know how to convert text/string data to numbers for a column in Dataframe ? 
If the same text/string appear again, they should return the same number. 
Looking for a general way to convert since there are thousands of fruit in the world
Example :
   Fruit         Number (expected outcome)
1  Apple         1
2  Orange        2
3  Apple         1
4  Banana        3
5  Blackberries  4
6  Avocado       5
7  Grapes        6
8  Orange        2
9  Apple         1
10 Mango         7
.  .             .
.  .             .
.  .             .

Comment: Hi Sirimiri - See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884039/oracle-sql-convert-string-to-number-with-exceptions-to-treat-text-as-0). It should answer your question.

Comment: Use `df['Number'] = pd.factorize(df.Fruit)[0] + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 

fruitList={'name':[ "Apple","Orange","Apple","Banana","Blackberries","Avocado","Grapes","Orange","Apple","Mango"] }
df = pd.DataFrame(fruitList) 

# get distinct fruit names
unique=df.name.unique()
# generating a dictionary based on Id of unique fruit names using list comprehension
dict={ x:index+1 for index, x in enumerate(unique) }
# assigning new column 'Id' values from the dictionary using the map function 
df['Id']  = df["name"].map(dict)
print(df)
```

The Output is :

```
        name      Id
0         Apple   1
1        Orange   2
2         Apple   1
3        Banana   3
4  Blackberries   4
5       Avocado   5
6        Grapes   6
7        Orange   2
8         Apple   1
9         Mango   7
```