# Can I conditionally change the Type of a where condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle (PL)SQL, I currently have a table with key - value pairs. And need to search by different conditions (like smaller than or contains)

I'm currently trying to conditionally (regex) change the datatype of a column inside my where condition, so that I'm able to use a smaller than < condition for the number datatype.
The problem I'm guessing is, that sql is confused about it, because in some cases it would need to compare a string and in others a number.

In my table I know that every element which has attr_id (basically a group) 11 is a string, 8 is an iso-date and 6 is a number (if there's a way to utilize that)

Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE attr_value (id, attr_id, value) AS
  SELECT 1, 11, 'abc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 11, 'test123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 6, '123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 8, '2021-12-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 6, '789' FROM DUAL;
```

Select:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    attr_value av
WHERE av.attr_id = 6 
AND CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(av.VALUE, '^[-+]?[0-9]+$') 
  THEN CAST(av.VALUE AS NUMBER) 
  ELSE av.VALUE 
END < 250
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9dae1841bd9d7e993fc53b7992e97149

Thanks in advance

Comment: An expression can only ever return a single data type. You can't have different types on different rows.  Also, `'abc' < 250` makes no sense, what do you want/expect to happen for those rows?

Comment: I'll probably need 2 selects then, in my mind 'abc' < 250 should never happen as I check if the attr_id = 6, which tells me the value can only be a number

Comment: That would assume the filters are applied in the order you wrote them. But SQL isn't an imperative language, it's declarative; the engine is free to find whatever mechanism it sees as best to solve the problem declared. Which is why using scopes (sub-queries) becomes important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to assert that one filter is applied before another, the simplest way is to use two different scopes *(relying on the order in which they're written won't work, owing to SQL being declarative rather than imperative)*. The first scope restricts to atrribute 6, and the second scope restricts to values below 250.

That means using sub-queries.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=73e2fe1f5ea0d5dae4e78c725db38c2c

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM attr_value WHERE attr_id = 6
)
  av
WHERE
  CAST(av.VALUE AS NUMBER) < 250
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code will not reliably work in Oracle. While you're getting lucky with this example, there are many cases where Oracle will use query transformations such as predicate pushing to move a condition inside an inline view. To force an inline view to run first, you would need to either use hints or a trick like adding a `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot dynamically change the type in SQL, since version 12.2 you can use `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` to ignore errors:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    attr_value av
WHERE av.attr_id = 6 
  AND TO_NUMBER(value DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) < 250;
```

But you still have to hope that every programmer remembers to do that every time. And you have to hope that you don't have a configuration that hits a [weird parsing bug with `ON CONVERSION ERROR`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66037720/409172).

A more permanent solution would be to change your data model to store every value as their native type. As I explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31769013/409172), it's simpler, safer, and faster to change the one `VALUE` column to three or more columns like `NUMBER_VALUE`, `STRING_VALUE`, and `DATE_VALUE`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should've specified the version, sadly the database is still on 11g Release 11.2. I will discuss the other option which you linked with my colleagues and see if it's a feasible change